# MySQL select distinct with inner join and where. What indexes to create?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_a.id FROM table_a 
INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.profile_id
WHERE table_b.role_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I have an index on table_b:

```
CREATE INDEX test_index ON table_b (role_id, profile_id)
```

But EXPLAIN gives me 'use temporary' for table_b

```
Using where; Using index; Using temporary
```

What indexes should I create to overcome this?

Update:
Explain output

```
| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys               | key        | key_len | ref                | rows  | Extra                                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_b | range  | table_b_e1c74d82,test_index | test_index | 5       | NULL               | 12860 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_a | eq_ref | PRIMARY                     | PRIMARY    | 4       | table_b.profile_id |     1 | Using index                               |
```

The `table_b_e1c74d82` index is a `(profile_id, production_id, role_id)` index.

Comment: Can we see the full `EXPLAIN` result? The `DISTINCT` is probably giving you that.

Comment: Question updated. 
Yes, it's the distinct. But that causes an enormous performance drop. AFAIK this is due to the using temporary.

Comment: I have a feeling that MySQL 5.6 might be able to optimize this with the [BKA join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bnl-bka-optimization.html), which you could explicitly enable for this query.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need following indexes for this:

```
role_id in table_b
profile_id in table_b
id in table_a
```

MySQL will run its optimiser on the query and will the pick the best one for the job.

Using temporary just means that to resolve the query, MySQL needs to create a temporary table to hold the result. This typically happens if the query contains `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses that list columns differently.

Comment: Yes, it is because of the `DISTINCT`. But that's causing a major performance drop so I'd like to prevent a `using temporary`.

Comment: You have composite index on `(role_id, profile_id)`, do you have only on `profile_id` also, if not you can try if having it improves performance, as it will be used  in `join`.

Comment: Also, I don't think the composite index will be very useful, it will be equivalent of having index only on `role_id`.